# Fault in reticulate in rstudio

Tags: anaconda, python-3.7

476/5000
rstudio generates error when running R code with python code.  At first the code worked very well but in the second installation it started to generate faults. Here is the link of the code in case you want to play #https: //www.r-bloggers.com/r-and-python-using-reticulate-to-get-the-best-of-both-worlds/
. My laptop is hp 4 gigs of ram and 500 mb of hard disk.
I would greatly appreciate who can explain the failure and how to solve it.

I have reinstalled anaconda last version twice.

> library(reticulate)
>   use_python("/usr/local/bin/python")
>
> use_virtualenv("r-reticulate")
>
> os  <- import("os")
>   Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
>                                          WARNING: The conda.compat modul
>                        (right here) ------^
>   os$listdir(".")
>   Error: object 'os' not found
>   py_config()
>   Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
>                                          WARNING: The conda.compat modul
>                        (right here) ------^

Comment: Now run this script from  #https: //www.r-bloggers.com/r-and-python-using-reticulate-to-get-the-best-of-both-worlds/ . and in the middle of script the output of repl_python()
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.

Comment: session_info() R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Chile.1252     

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be useful for you: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/switch-environment/

I have Anaconda, and set up Python 2 environment. Once activated, run 'use_python' with the path to that environment and set the 'required' parameter to TRUE.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it comes from a deprecation warning reported a few days ago ([fix compat import showing warning #8507](https://github.com/conda/conda/pull/8507)).
But the fact is that this warning in "*conda.compat*" generates some errors, for example in the case of using conda environments in R through "*reticulate*" functions. This issue has been reported quite recently [Conda warnings taken as errors #477](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/477).

The solution is to simply install the **github version of "*reticulate*"** in order to avoid these errors and ignore the conda warnings which shouldn't necessarily impede these functionalities. You can do it like this way:

```
remotes::install_github("rstudio/reticulate")
```

And don't forget to have the latest Rtools installed in your operating system!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved the problem by installing an older version of conda.

In anaconda promt

conda install conda = 4.1.6